# Why can't I run programs on another partition in Linux?

Tags: permissions, executable, chmod

So for convenience, I store all my data on my Windows partition so that I can access my data easily from both Linux and Windows. However, I tried compiling a C++ program with g++, and found out that I cannot run the program with `./program_filename`, as it tells me

```
bash: program_filename: Permission denied
```

Doing

```
cp program_filename ~/program_filename
```

and running it from my home directory works just fine, however.

So I tried `chmod +rwx program_filename`, but `ls -l` shows that the permissions are still set as `-rw-------.` for all files in the directory. Nothing changes when I do this as root, either.

Is there a simple fix for this?

(In case it's useful, I am running Fedora 16 x64)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure that your mount options allow the execute permission bit.

There are mount options one can use to limit the permissions of files within the mounted filesystem: general `noexec` prevents all files from being executable, FAT-specific option `showexec` grants the permission only to files with extensions `.exe`, `.com` and `.bat`. Note also that `noexec` is implied by `user` and `users`.

If you use `user` or `users` you can still get the execute permission bit working by mounting with explicitly specified `exec` mount option after the `user` or `users` option.

See mount [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) for details.

Answer (score 6):

When you mount a FAT or NTFS partition, the permissions are determined at mount time, by the `umask`, `fmask` and `dmask` options. The first is general, the other two are specific for files and directories.

Also you may be interested in `uid` and `gid` option to establish the owner and group of all files and directory on the partition.

An example:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g -o uid=500,gid=500,umask=0022 /dev/sda1 /mnt/win
```

Answer (score -1):

In Puppy Linux, by default you can execute scripts on NTFS or FAT partitions: http://murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=95174

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Since links often go stale, [it is always preferred](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.