# Can not run executable files from a mounted drive

Tags: linux, permissions, linux-mint, mount, executable

I have downloaded eclipse and rubymine and previously placed in home folder. Then I used to open both programs by double clicking on eclipse.sh and rubymine.sh.

Now I moved these two folders in a mounted drive. But when I double click on eclipse.sh and rubymine.sh they open in text editor. So I went rubymine.sh->properties->permission and there is a checkbox for "execute: allow executing file as program". This checkbox is not checked. Even if I check it, it gets unchecked automatically. So the executable files do not run as executable programs. But how can run my programs from mounted drive?

Also I tried to run it from command line. But I get permission denied

```
asis@asis /media/asis/Other/Linux/RubyMine-8.0.1/bin $ chmod +x rubymine.sh
asis@asis /media/asis/Other/Linux/RubyMine-8.0.1/bin $ ./rubymine.sh
-bash: ./rubymine.sh: Permission denied
```

I don't want to keep the programs in the home directory. I want them to keep in a mounted drive. I am using Linux mint 17.3

Comment: What filesystem are you using for the mounted drive? Windows-targeted file systems often do not have an x bit you can flip on a per-file basis. (Linux-targeted systems could be mounted `noexec`, but that's unusual these days.)

Comment: I am using windows filesystem for mounted drive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I run programs on another partition in Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29089/why-cant-i-run-programs-on-another-partition-in-linux). Solution is to add the `exec` mount option **after** the `user` or `users` option. Where to do this depends on whether you use udisks or /etc/fstab to do the mounting.

Answer (score 4):

Some systems doesn't allow to execute files in user mounted devices, using the option `noexec`.   Check with `cat /proc/mounts` if this is the case, and remount the filesystem with exec permissions.

Comment: I am using windows filesystem for mounted drive.  Could you please show me the commands? I am totally new in linux world